# регулярные выражения в pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Имеется фрейм данных

```
0      [143:138 (32:32,34:31,32:31,24:28,21:16)]
1             [344:334(93:83,86:91,65:67,79:77)]
2                                    [0:0 (0:0)]
3             [109:95 (39:24,23:30,14:17,33:24)]
4             [92:101 (22:27,29:30,19:19,22:25)]

215            [82:68 (13:20,24:15,25:23,20:10)]
216            [91:72 (21:17,14:22,25:12,31:21)]
217            [73:65 (12:18,23:10,20:14,18:23)]
218            [84:78 (19:24,18:16,24:28,23:10)]
219            [73:84 (23:23,17:19,15:23,18:19)]
```

пытаюсь его разобрать на отдельные series регулярными выражениями

```
res = s.str.extract(r'^\[(?P<fullscore>\S+?)\s\((.+?)\)')
res = pd.concat([res['fullscore'], res[1].str.split(",", expand=True)], axis=1)
```

Но постоянно выдает

```
    fullscore   0
0         NaN NaN
1         NaN NaN
2         NaN NaN
3         NaN NaN
4         NaN NaN
..        ...  ..
215       NaN NaN
216       NaN NaN
217       NaN NaN
218       NaN NaN
219       NaN NaN

[220 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Не вижу проблемы — для меня это работает. Проверите, если элементы серии `s` являются строками: `type(s[0])` нужно быть `str`.

Answer (score 0):

помогло:

```
df['scores']=df['scores'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, расширьте ответ так, чтобы он мог помочь другим